# Apply a transformation matrix to a list of coordinates

Tags: matlab, coordinates, vectorization, transformation, bsxfun

I have an array of `N` position vectors which form an *N*-by-*3* matrix. I want to transform these position vectors to another coordinate system. The *3*-by-*3* rotational transformation matrix is same for all position vectors. How can I use `arrayfun` or `bsxfun` for this purpose for minimising computation time?

Comment: what transformation do you want? There are [various availabe](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cartesian-coordinate-system-conversion.html)

Comment: FYI `arrayfun` is very unlikely to minimise computation time over a simple `for`-loop. It's just wrapping a loop up with a bit of extra overhead. `bsxfun` does produce a speedup often, however matrix multiplication with `bsxfun` is not simple. Luckily for you, you need neither as `*` will suffice.

Comment: @Dan, I wonder though: why is *N*-by-*3* better than `Nx3`? Both `N` and `3` should be code, I believe (but the former definitely). And you don't need superfluous edits for a title change.

Comment: @AndrasDeak so mostly because `N` and *N* are completely different in this case and the ambiguity caused by writing `Nx3` is precisely why I prefer to use MATLAB's documentation's formatting. `Nx3` could be a variable name, `N*3` is even worse as it could be the matix `N` (which actually exists in this case!) multiplied by the scalar `3`. Since *N* and *3* in this case are never actually typed in code but rather almost meta data to the data structures in the code, I prefer to not use code tags for them. If it was *`n`*-by-*3* I would though if `n` was a variable.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Regarding the title change, I disagree. Question titles are what draw future searches to questions so I think it is vital that they actually reflect what is being asked and answered. I found the original title misleading

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see he said array of `N` position vectors which I misread as an array `N` of position vectors. Mostly because I expect something in code tags to be a variable, but in this instance I see my error and the two `N`s are indeed the same. Personally I think that neither should be in code tags though.

Comment: @Dan you misunderstood part of my comment: I don't have anything against the title change. I just noted that your typographical change must have been intentional, because you could've edited the title without touching anything else. And I see your point about formatting. I usually use space, `N x 3`, which excludes the case of a variable name. I don't see italics in the matlab docs, however;) But fair enough, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

You can just apply it in one shot using matrix multiplication:

```
NTransformed = N*transformationMatrix
```

Comment: The beauty of matrix multiplication